# jQuery and dynamically generated forms

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, field

I am creating form fields dynamically.

---

If I use

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {

    $("input[name=salesPrice1]").blur(function() {

        var nameID = $("input[name=salesPrice1]").val();

        alert(nameID);

        //var newName = $("input#newName").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cashPrice.cfm",
            data: "salePrice=" + $("input[name=salesPrice1]").val(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#cashPrice1").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

It will partially work. Now, I have to get the ID/Name of the formField dynamically. How do I do this?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Update it.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what you call the ID/Name of the formField, neither what you mena by dynamically.

Comment: somehow it didn't post my server side code. I have 
<form>
 some coldfusion loop ...
 <input type="text" name="salesPrice#i#" id="salesPrice#i#" value="">
 <div id="cashPrice#i#"></div>
</form>

Comment: so this line:$("input[name=salesPrice1]").
somehow get the correct id for the text input. Like 1,2,3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ?

```
$("input[name^=salesPrice]").each(function(){
    var input = $(this); 
    var name = input.attr('name');
    var num = /\d+$/.exec(name)[0];

    $(this).blur(function() {

        var nameID = input.val();

        alert(nameID);

        //var newName = $("input#newName").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cashPrice.cfm",
        data: "salePrice=" + nameID,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#cashPrice"+num).html(data);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: almost. I had to change : 
 data: "salePrice=" + input.val(),

Comment: Wups... Ok, let's use nameID which has already been computed before then. Edited the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague at best. But is this somewhat along the lines of what you want?:

```
$("input").blur(function ()
{
    var that = $(this);

    var id = that.attr("id");
    var name = that.attr("name");
});
```

**Update:**

You can match elements on values:

```
$("input[id^='hello']")
```

Will match:

```
<input type="text" id="helloworld" />
<input type="text" id="helloearth" />
```

But not:

```
<input type="text" id="hiworld" />
```

See the [selector documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

**NOTICE:** these selectors are slow and I would only use 'em as a last resort. To speed up performance, you can do queries on a subset of DOM nodes:

```
$("complex selector goes here", $("container node in which to query"))
```

Comment: I am having trouble with the code formatting on this site. I have the following 
<script>
$().ready(function() {
alert(1);
 $("input").blur(function ()
 {    var that = $(this);    
   var id = that.attr("id");   
   var name = that.attr("name");
   });
});
</script>


<body>
<form>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="3" index="i">
<input type="text" name="salesPrice#i#" id="salesPrice#i#" value="" />
<div id="cashPrice#i#"></div>
<hr />
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
</form>
I don't think i can simply use $("input") since this function needs to be applied to only salesPrice.

Comment: Also, I can see the alert(1) when the page loads,but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

this also works:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        alert('loaded');
        $('.salesPriceInput').blur(function ()
        {    
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            var myID = $(this).attr("id").substr(10,1); 
            alert(myID);
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "cashPrice.cfm",
                data: "salePrice=" + $('#salesPrice'+myID).val(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                   $('#cashPrice'+myID).html(data);
                }
            })
         }); 
    });
</script>


<form>
    <cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to="3" index="i">
            <input type="text" name="salesPrice#i#" id="salesPrice#i#" class="salesPriceInput" value="" />
            <div id="cashPrice#i#"></div>
            <hr />
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
</form>
```

Comment: The text editor keeps ignoring my <form> 
I meant to add <form>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="3" index="i">
<input type="text" name="salesPrice#i#" id="salesPrice#i#" class="salesPriceInput" value="" />
<div id="cashPrice#i#"></div>
<hr />
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
</form>

Comment: You should skip lines and indent the code with at least 4 spaces for the formatter to format your code. Be careful with substr : some day you may change the names in your coldfusion file and forget to update your javascript code... then you'll scratch your head pretty hard.

Comment: I edited your answer to fix the formatting. Need to put 4 spaces in front of code for it to render properly.